# Error:Malformed head of type or class declaration

Tags: haskell

I tried the following code in ghci in ubuntu.

```
data Btree a=Ebt|Node a (Btree a)(Btree a)
t=Node 10( Node 20 Ebt Ebt) (Node 30 Ebt Ebt)
```

The compiler shows the error: `Malformed head of type or class declaration`

The compiler compiles others code well. Can you please help me to find out the problem?

Comment: I'm running an old version of GHC, so I can't do datatype declarations directly in ghci, but when I paste this in a `test.hs` file and load that it works fine. Perhaps the error is in another part of your code?

Comment: Jamey , it shud b corrct, U conform me. these are the lines I have.I dnt knw then whethr it is da compiler prblm or not. But ghci compiles others code well. Do u have any suggestions den?

Comment: You should reduce it to the smallest program you can that doesn't compile, then post that full program and the full compiler error message. Otherwise it's unlikely that anyone can help. Also, tell us what version of GHC you're using (`ghc --version`).

Comment: I am using the code to find the root of the tree:                                                            data bTree a = Ebt|Node a (bTree a)(bTree a)
t=Node 10(Node 20(Node 50 Ebt Ebt) Ebt)(Node 30(Node 40 Ebt Ebt) (Node 60 Ebt Ebt))deriving show

getRoot (Node a _ _)=a
getRoot Ebt=Error "Empty"

Comment: You can't put a `deriving` clause after a function declaration--it has to be on the datatype that you want to derive an instance for. Also, the "Show" class is capitalized, and case matters. And "bTree" needs to start with a capital letter too, since it's a type name. And that comment is super difficult to read; you should edit your original question with the code you want us to look at.

Comment: Jamey, many  many thanx to u.........Take my gratitude. U just show me the errors. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. It runs successfully now/

Answer (score 14):

Since I apparently answered the question, I'm writing it here as an answer that I hope you'll click the "accept" button on.

- You can't put a deriving clause after a function declaration--it has to be on the datatype that you want to derive an instance for.
- The "Show" class is capitalized, and case matters.
- "bTree" needs to start with a capital letter too, since it's a type name.

Comment: 2 yrs ago... so heavy haha

Comment: @lol Still waiting